# Doctrine ODM MongoDB - ReferenceOne vs ReferenceMany

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm

I am very new to Doctrine and MongoDB. I have configured Doctrine ODM and started learning it. While going through documentation I am very much confused on ReferenceOne and ReferenceMany annotations  used in that.

Can anyone please help me on this to give me a clear picture of their difference? Also when to use which one?

```
ReferenceOne vs ReferenceMany
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not worked on Doctrine or MongoDB. but the logic for ReferenceOne vs ReferenceMany. is
i will give a small example which will make you little bit clear.
Let's consider we have a user table, user profile table, user address table. Using these three table i will explain the relation.

1) A user can have only one profile mapped to the user account.(ReferenceOne)

2) But the same user can have more than one address mapped to his account.(ReferenceMany)

I think this will make you clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is in the context of deciding on the relationship between collections.  for example, if you have a collection of people, and a collection of cities -- a person can live only in one place -- so each document in the people collection would reference exactly one document in the cities collection. A city document, on the other hand, can have many people living in it -- so each city document would have an array of references (many) to people documents.
This is a very contrived and horrible example -- designing a city collection with an array of millions of people references is not a good idea, but i hope it clarifies the difference